# Laravel 5 and Vue JS blank page

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use Vue JS on my Laravel 5 application, it gives me the blank page when I used **v-**

```
            new Vue({
                el: '#vApp',
                data: {
                    todos: [
                        { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
                        { text: 'Learn Vue' },
                        { text: 'Build something awesome' }
                      ],
                      message: "Welcome"
                  },
                delimiters: ["%%","%%"]
            });
```

if I just print the message into the blade view page it works well

```
<div id="vApp">%% message %%</div>
```

When I am trying to use

```
 <li v-for="todo in todos">
      %% todo.text %%
 </li>
```

or

```
  <input v-model="message">
```

it give me the blank page

Comment: Any error messages in the Developer Console?

Comment: no error in developer console

Answer (score 0):

The default build exported by the NPM package is the runtime-only build. It doesn’t bring the template compiler. So you would either need to import the full build version of vue in your javascript or create a webpack alias (if you are using webpack).

This issue won't occur when you define templates with the render function or Single File Component.

NOTE:

You don't need `babel-loader` if you dont expect to support older browsers and if you dont use latest ES features and you won't need `vue-loader` if you are not using Single File Components.

Also note that you must include the meta tag in your HTML `<meta charset="utf-8">`

This would work -

```js
// webpack
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./app.js"],
  output: { filename: "./app.min.js" },
  resolve: { alias: { vue: "vue/dist/vue.js" } },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

```js
// app.js

import Vue from "vue";
// import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';

window.app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { text: "Learn Vue" },
      { text: "Build something awesome" }
    ],
    message: "Welcome"
  },
  delimiters: ["%%", "%%"]
});
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <p>%% message %%</p>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
        %% todo.text %%
    </li>
    <input v-model="message">
</div>
<script src="app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you wrapped the contents by vApp?
Like this:

```
<div id="vApp">
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
        %% todo.text %%
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I tried still the blank page, even in the input if I remove the 'v-' page contents displaying. If I add it back it goes blank

Comment: You did change delimiters (default {{ }} -> %% %%)
Have a try with this
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
        %% todo.text %%
    </li>

Comment: Hi, @muthamizhchelvan-v
Can you share the whole code, please?

Below is a codepen of the above code working well.
https://codepen.io/adevshark/pen/agPbGJ